# Using a selection from a drop down list to update a db query

Tags: php, sql

I'm populating a drop down list from a database (that part works) and when I select an item from the drop down I want it to use the newly selected items info and run it through my functions to calculate the items life cycle (each item has a life cycle entered into the database in years). When I hard code the item_num into the query it works fine but when I try to use the drop down to make my selection it returns nothing. Obviously, I'm missing something elementary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'databaseConnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['itemDropDown'])) {
$submittedValue = $_POST['itemDropDown'];
}

$query = $db->query("select life_cycle, entered_into_service from assets, 
all_items where assets.type = all_items.type and assets.make = 
all_items.make and assets.model = all_items.model and all_items.item_num 
='.$submittedValue'");

$userRow=$query->fetchAll();

function dateDifference($date_1, $date_2, $differenceFormat = '%a')
   {
   $dateTime1 = date_create($date_1);
   $dateTime2 = date_create($date_2);

   $interval = date_diff($dateTime1, $dateTime2);

   return $interval->format($differenceFormat);
   }

function daysRemaining($entered, $life)
{
 $date_1 = $entered;
 $date_2 = date('m/d/Y');
 echo (365 * $life) - dateDifference($date_1, $date_2) ." days";
}

function get_items() {
global $db;
$query = 'SELECT item_num, type, make, model FROM all_items
          ORDER BY item_num';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
return $statement;    
}

$itemsInfo = get_items();
?>


<html>
    <head>
    <title>Date Difference</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainStyle.css">
    <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>       
</head>

<body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Days remaining in service:</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($userRow as $value) : ?>
                    <tr>
                     <td><?php 
     daysRemaining($value['entered_into_service'], $value['life_cycle']); ?>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>

    <form action="" name="items" method="post" > 
        <label>Available Items:</label>
            <select id="itemDropDown" name="itemDropDown">
                <option selected="selected">Choose an Item</option>
                <?php foreach ($itemsInfo as $itemInfo) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $itemInfo['item_num']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $itemInfo['item_num']; ?>
                        <?php echo $itemInfo['type']; ?>
                        <?php echo $itemInfo['make']; ?>
                        <?php echo $itemInfo['model']; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? What does `var_dump` display?

Comment: You should use a prepared query instead of substituting the variable into the SQL, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: When the user initially loads the page without submitting the form, `$submittedValue` will be empty and your query will get a syntax error.

Comment: No error is displayed. When I debug the project the '$userRow' is returning 'array(0)' so obviously there's some issue with how I'm putting in the '.$submittedValue'

Comment: Yes, @Barmar it does initially display an error but if I hit submit I would expect it to take the submitted value and populate my screen correctly but instead it shows nothing

Comment: Add `var_dump($userRow);` to see if the query is finding anything.

Comment: var_dump displays array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Why is there a period in the query, just before the $submittedValue variable   ='.$submittedValue'" ? This changes the matching criteria.

Comment: @Jonathan Spiller, That was a tremendous help! I knew I was missing something simple. The second problem: when the page initially loads there's an error because $submittedValue is empty. How do I fix that?

Comment: @digiteeb Currently you only initialize $submittedValue if $_POST['itemDropDown'] is set.  When it's not set, $submittedValue remains uninitialized. So initialize it either way. Try a ternary operator:  $submittedValue = (isset($_POST['itemDropDown'])) ? $_POST['itemDropDown'] : '';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $db->query("select life_cycle, entered_into_service
    from assets, all_items where assets.type = all_items.type
    and assets.make = all_items.make and assets.model = all_items.model
    and all_items.item_num ='.$submittedValue'");
```

Remove the dot before **$submittedValue**